# Angle of shoulder labrum

Tags: anatomy

Is the shoulder labrum 90 degrees from the front of a person?  Or is it offset a few degrees from perpendicular?  What about on the Z axis-- is the labrum straight up-and-down or is it angled vertically?  And what's a good online resource to help me to better understand the anatomy of the shoulder which seems more complex than other joints because there are multiple layers of tendons and muscle surrounding it.

I'm asking because I've had a torn labrum for a few decades and finally had a Bankart repair 4 years ago. One thing I've found helpful in this (long!) recovery is visualizing the anatomy of the shoulder so that when a particular motion is painful I can understand exactly what is hurting so I can try to avoid that part and/or strengthen other parts around it. My long-term goal is to train my muscles to provide the stability that my labrum can no longer provide.  But without knowing exactly what's going on in there, this goal is hard to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. Some may disagree but I feel this question is just about ok for this site, but it is bordering on being off-topic due to being related to personal medical advice. The question on the anatomy of the shoulder may have a better fit with Biology.SE. [For a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748), we can not, and will not, give medical advice. With regard to building muscular support for the labrum, it may be wise to seek the advice of a doctor or licensed physiotherapist.

Comment: Hi Chris - Thanks for the note. Would it be better if I removed the second paragraph? I'm interested in understanding the anatomy better, not medical advice.

Comment: The web is full of detailed anatomical drawings of the shoulder so if those don't answer your question I'm not sure how we could. In any case, how to develop a training program for a particular purpose is off topic here but on topic in the Physical Fitness exchange.